# Update all column rows with random values from another table in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to update all rows of a column with random values selected from another table. I am trying following query -

```
UPDATE TEST_CITY
    SET "CITY" = (SELECT NAME FROM CITY SAMPLE (1 rows))
```

The subquery gives me a random city when executed separately, but in above case all rows are updated with same value.

I have also tried to select random records by id like following but this also updates all rows with same value -

```
UPDATE TEST_CITY
    SET "CITY" = (select c.name
                  from city c
                  where c.id = (SELECT uniform(1, 50, random()))
                 )
```

This query for example updates all rows with different random values-

```
UPDATE TEST_CITY
    SET "name" = to_varchar(ABS(MOD(RANDOM(1), 1000000)))
```

Can I have something equivalent to this when random values are strings and should come from a separate table ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specifically for Snowflake, but other databases sometimes optimize subqueries with a volatile function, resulting in a single value.

One solution that I've seen work is to use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE TEST_CITY
    SET "CITY" = (select c.name
                  from city c
                  where c.id = (SELECT uniform(1, 50, random())) AND
                        test_city.city is not null -- any condition should do
                 );
```

Although the performance is likely to be worse, perhaps `order by` will work:

```
UPDATE TEST_CITY
    SET "CITY" = (select c.name
                  from city c
                  order by random()
                  limit 1
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. There are ways to make it work on other databases like you have mentioned, but i was facing issues specifically to Snowflake. I was able to find a solution and have posted as an answer.

Comment: @Sanjeev . . . So the correlation clause doesn't work in Snowflake?

Comment: Sorry I am late but I did check these queries and they update all rows with same value; same problem I've been facing when using random or uniform in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Below code run for me

```
UPDATE TEST_CITY a  SET a.CITY = b.NAME FROM (
SELECT NAME ,row_number()  over (order by random()) AS id from CITY) b;
```

Answer (score -1):

Following query worked for me. I have used hash on column name to make the update work on all rows of my column -

> UPDATE "TEST_CITY" SET "CITY" =  C."NAME" FROM CITY C WHERE C."ID" =
>   ABS(HASH("CITY")%16917) + 1 ;

16197 are the number of rows I have in City table.

Thanks